# if/else trouble - else not printing to console

Tags: python

My code runs through fine if I enter a word, but if I want to test the "else" part of it by not entering anything and just hitting enter when asked for a name, it returns "Oops, try again! Does your code print "empty" when len(original) is 0?"
To explain, I'm trying to complete a course on codecademy.

I've looked around and I just don't see why it shouldn't print "empty" into the console. Anyone got a clue? Does the fault lie with the lesson or is there really a mistake in the following code that'd keep it from printing the "empty" to the console?

```
print "Welcome!"
original = raw_input("Please enter a word")
if len("original") > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are checking the length of a string literal "original", which will always be greater than `0`.

```
if len("original") > 0:
```

change this to...

```
if len(original) > 0:
```

Comment: Oh gee, now I see it and I feel extremely silly. Thanks a lot for the swift help!

Answer (score 1):

Change `("original")` to `(original)`. When something is in quotes, Python evaluates it as a string. So here, you are simply checking the length of the word "original" which is always going to be larger than 0. If you put in (original), Python will evaluate it as a variable that you defined previously.

In a nutshell: you want the function to evaluate a variable, not a string literal (which is defined by "").